# NextJS - How do I make an api fetch with the use of a router id? Also how do I render it as html?

Tags: javascript, api, next.js

Hello I'm writing code in NextJS and am currently trying to do a user page that displays user specific information from an API. I want to load the id query from the address bar and use that to make an API call.

The API looks like this;
/Users/{id}

Furthermore I need some help to load that data to the rendered page.

In the address bar the link looks like this:
http://localhost:3000/userPage?id=2

So this is what my code look like on page userPage:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function GetQuery(){
  const router = useRouter();
  const id = router.query.id;
  return id; 
}


export const getServerSidePros = async (id) =>  {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/User/${id}`);
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { users: data },
  };
};


const UserPage = (users) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h1>{users.name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't think the id from the adress bar is being picked up.
I get Hello to render but nothing else.

Also the GetQuery function is never read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
export const getServerSidePros = async (context) =>  {
  const { id } = context.query;

  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/User/${id}`);
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { users: data },
  };
};


const UserPage = ({users}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h1>{users.name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can use `context.query` inside the `getServerSidePros` to access the query params.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! It works flawlessly!!!!
Exactly what I wanted!